# How to select multiple buttons and keep the border on each one clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So we have 4 buttons and when we click on one it gets a black border but when you click another button the previous button loses its border and the new one gets it.

```js
const btnPlaces = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-places');

for (let i = 0; i < btnPlaces.length; i++) {
  btnPlaces[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let prevBtn = document.querySelector(".checked");
    if (prevBtn) {
      prevBtn.classList.remove("checked");
      e.target.classList.add("checked");
    } else {
      e.target.classList.add("checked");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.checked {
  border: 3px solid rgb(34, 34, 34);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-places" id="berlin">BERLIN</button>
<button class="btn-places" id="netherlands">NETHERLANDS</button>
<button class="btn-places" id="sweden">SWEDEN</button>
<button class="btn-places" id="italy">ITALY</button>
```

Is there an alternative solution that is more efficient?

Comment: You can se a radio input for this

Comment: Are you trying to keep the black border on the button when it's selected even if another button is clicked? In other words... do you want to see multiple buttons with the border?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question. Don't YELL AT US.

Comment: Short answer: You're using the wrong control. This is why checkboxes exist.

Comment: @Millhorn only the one you select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) state in CSS. Only one element is active at the time with `:focus` state.

```css
.btn-places:focus {
  border: 3px solid rgb(34, 34, 34);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-places" id="berlin">BERLIN</button>
<button class="btn-places" id="netherlands">NETHERLANDS</button>
<button class="btn-places" id="sweden">SWEDEN</button>
<button class="btn-places" id="italy">ITALY</button>
```

Comment: wow that was easy , but i guess you cant scale it from there.  how do you select the one button with focus so you can get data and manipulate it?

Comment: You can use `onClick` for every click on those buttons. If you want to keep the selected button,  I think radio button is more suitable for you :D @NickGlav

Answer (score 0):

You can use an input radio to it, it will provide you a pseudo-selector `::checked` where you can style as you wish
It's provide a onchecked callback function too to use your javascript to do something

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to keep the button border even when another is clicked. In that case, you would need to remove:

```
prevBtn.classList.remove("checked");
```

from your condition.

```js
const btnPlaces = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-places');

for (let i = 0; i < btnPlaces.length; i++) {
  btnPlaces[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let prevBtn = document.querySelector(".checked");
    if (prevBtn) {
      e.target.classList.add("checked");
    } else {
      e.target.classList.add("checked");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.checked {
  border: 3px solid rgb(34, 34, 34);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-places" id="berlin">BERLIN</button>
<button class="btn-places" id="netherlands">NETHERLANDS</button>
<button class="btn-places" id="sweden">SWEDEN</button>
<button class="btn-places" id="italy">ITALY</button>
```

Comment: It doesn't really sound like he wants to keep border when clicking on another button, it sounds more like his code is working as intended but he just wants to know if there is a better way of doing it

Comment: The OP says, ***when we click on one it gets a black border but when you click another button the previous button loses its border and the new one gets it.*** - That indicates to me the behavior that's happening is what he's trying to avoid. He's knew... just doesn't know how to ask the right question.